# Auto Unlock - supported

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-pro, settings, apple-watch, system-information

For a MacBook Pro mid 2014 macOS High Sierra in the System Report I just want to verify that -Auto Unlock - Supported- is telling me that it is possible for me to set up a Apple Watch and it is not telling me that it is on or setup. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/12/28/how-to-check-if-your-mac-supports-auto-unlock/):

> If you see “Auto Unlock: Supported,” your Mac meets Auto Unlock hardware requirements. If not, you’re out of luck. As a rule of thumb, Mac models manufactured before 2013 cannot use Auto Unlock.

So it looks like it's telling you the Mac **supports** Auto Unlock.  I have a 2015 MPB with Auto Unlock turned on and my system report still says 'Supported'.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the link you provided and I realized under  Auto Unlock: Supported it says Status - Connected.

Comment: I am not aware of any way my computer can Auto Unlock. I do not want my computer to Auto Unlock. How can I see what it is and turn it off. Or just turn it off?

Comment: I don't know if that 'Status - Connected' is for the network card or something else.  I don't think it's for the Auto Unlock feature.

Comment: If you don't want the feature, which is different than the original question you asked, just don't enable it in `Security & Privacy`.  If that option's not checked, it won't unlock with your Watch.